# What are the 3 worlds of the Kli Yakar?

Tags: commentaries, parashat-bereishit, parashat-noach

The Kli Yakar talks about 3 created worlds. What is he referring to?

[Kli Yakar Bereshit 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.1.1.4?lang=bi):

> ‏ויש עוד דרך שלישי, אבל אין כל אדם יכול לעמוד עליו והוא להכיר מציאת‏ השם ית' מתוך החקירה וידיעת כל הנמצאים שבכל שלשה עולמות וזה סדרם מתחילה צריך החוקר להתבונן במהות הנמצאים שבעולם התחתון כי היא החקירה הקלה שבעולם. ואחר ידיעת מהותם יתבונן גם במהות הנבראים שבעולם האמצעי. ומשם יעלה דרך סולם השתלשלות המדרגות לידיעת מהות העולם העליון. ומשם יעלה לידע ולהשיג כי יש ‏אלוה נמצא רוכב על כולם‏
>
> And there is also a third way [to know about the existence of God], but not every one is capable of it, and that is to come to know about the existence of God, may He be blessed, through investigation and knowledge of all that is to be found in all of the three worlds and this is their order: At first, the researcher must understand the essence of things in the lowest world, since it is the easiest research [that exists]. And after knowing their essence, he should [seek to] also understand the essence of the creatures of the middle world. And from there, he should go up, [as] with a ladder going up the different levels, to know the essence of the highest world. And from there, he should go up to know and fathom that there is God who is found to ride upon all of them...

[Kli Yakar Bereshit 6:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.6.16?lang=bi):

> יש להתבונן אם היה צריך לחלק כל מדור ומדור לפי ענינו עליונים לאדם אמצעים למדור תחתונים לזבל א״כ למה לא צוה לעשותם בשטח אחד ולמה נעשו בזו על גב זו דוקא ורמז כאן שהיו ג' שטחים אלו בדמיון כל ג' עולמות, כי בזמן המבול נתקלקלו כל העולמות והמזלות לא שמשו כלל, ע״כ נעשית התיבה בציור זה להורות על קיומם.

Further on on Bereshit 6:16 he seems to split it up so that the upper world has the angels, middle world is the heavens, and the lower world is the earth.

If that is the distinctions between the worlds, what is the Kli Yakar's underlying philosophy to split the world into those categories?

Comment: I assume he means בריאה, יצירה, עשיה, although I understood the angels to be in יצירה

Comment: מדור העליון ומדור התחתון is in gemara avoda zara

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Kli Yakar is using the same model as R' Yosef Albo, in Sefer HaIkrim.

In [chapter 31 of the second Maamar, the Sefer HaIkrim](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/ikarim/b8-2.htm#3) discusses 3 worlds:

> כאשר עיינו במציאות בכללו נמצא אותו מתחלק לשלושה חלקים אי אפשר להכחיש מציאותם: 
>   **החלק האחד העולם התחתון** שהוא עולם היסודות וההויה וההפסד, 
>   והחלק הב' **עולם הגלגלים**, 
>   והחלק הג' **עולם המלאכים**.
>
> ואלו השלושה חלקים נבדלים זה מזה תכלית ההבדל:
>   כי אנחנו נמצא העולם התחתון שהוא עולם ההוויה וההפסד, כל אישיו נפסדים, אין להם קיום באיש כלל. 
>   ועולם הגלגלים כל אישיו קיימים באיש ובלתי נפסדים, אבל הם גשם וישיגם מקרי הגשם, שיש להם תמונה ותואר, וממלאים מקום, והם כמה, ומחוברים מחלקים.

to paraphrase, he says that we can split existence into 3 indisputable parts. The lower, physical part where nothing lasts forever, the middle part where the heavenly bodies are found, and the higher part, the world of the angels.

---

We see the Kli Yakar use this model in both the locations mentioned in the question. In [1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.1.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) he connects Yaakov's dream of the angels on the ladder to these three worlds:

> הסולם שהיה מוצב ארצה היינו השגת העולם התחתון. וראשו מגיע השמימה זהו העולם התיכון. והנה מלאכי אלהים עולים ויורדים בו זהו העולם העליון. והנה ה' נצב עליו כי אז השיג על השלימות מציאת הש״י.

The ladder was standing on the ground (lower world), it's head reached the heavens (middle world), angels (upper world) were ascending and descending. G-d is above all the created worlds.

In [6:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.6.16?lang=bi) the Kli Yakar explains why the worlds are structured this way. The closer they are to the source, the less elements they comprise. Angels are comprised of a single element, the heavens are comprised of 2 elements, and the earth and its creatures are comprised of all 4 elements.