# Difference between blessing and hallowing in Vaykhulu

Tags: parashat-bereishit, leil-shabbat

We read *Vaykhulu* [three times](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103378/15256) on the Shabbat eve, which includes the verse [Bereishit 2:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#3):

> **וַיְבָ֤רֶךְ** אֱלֹהִים֙ אֶת־י֣וֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י **וַיְקַדֵּ֖שׁ** אֹת֑וֹ כִּ֣י ב֤וֹ שָׁבַת֙ מִכָּל־מְלַאכְתּ֔וֹ אֲשֶׁר־בָּרָ֥א אֱלֹהִ֖ים לַֽעֲשֽׂוֹת׃
>
> And *Hashem* **blessed** the seventh day, and **hallowed** it; because that in it He rested from all His work which *Hashem* in creating had made.

What is the relevance of having these two similar words in the sentence? Do commentators expound upon this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rashi ad loc](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.2.3?lang=bi) (quoting [Bereishit Rabbah 11:2](https://archive.org/details/RabbaGenesis/page/n127)):

> בֵּרְכוֹ בַּמָּן, שֶׁכָּל יְמוֹת הַשָּׁבוּעַ יוֹרֵד לָהֶם עֹמֶר לַגֻּלְגֹּלֶת, וּבַשִּׁשִּׁי לֶחֶם מִשְׁנֶה, וְקִדְּשׁוֹ בַּמָּן, שֶׁלֹּא יָרַד כְּלָל בְּשַׁבָּת, וְהַמִּקְרָא כָּתוּב עַל הֶעָתִיד:‏
>
> He blessed it through the Manna, that on all other days of the week there should fall for them (the Israelites) an Omer for each person, whereas on the sixth day there should fall twice as much of that bread. So, too, He sanctified it through the Manna, that it should not fall at all on the Sabbath. This verse is written here with reference to what would happen in the future.
>
> *(Silbermann translation courtesy of sefaria.org)*

Comment: I have problems understanding this _midrash._ Am I correct if I say that the subject of both blessing and hallowing is the seventh day. In this case, the _blessing_ wouldn't go for the six weekdays?

Comment: I think that's correct

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65016/15256